# "Eta converting" type application

Tags: types, julia

Is there an existing way, in Base, Core, Core.Compiler, etc., to convert type application to function application?  In other terms, a pointfree replacement for the lambda in the following expression:

```
julia> ((T, U) -> Union{T, U})(Int, Bool)
Union{Bool, Int64}
```

I expected

```
Base.Fix1(Core.apply_type, Union)(Int, Bool)
```

to work, but unfortunately `Fix1` does not have a varargs method.

Answer (score 0):

The `->` pseudo-operator is just a way of creating an *anonymous* function.
Perhaps you want a non-anonymous function that does the same thing.

```
f(T, U) = Union{T, U}
```

might be one. It depends on what you expect the function to return though. 
The function above returns what the -> example you gave does:

```
julia> f(Int, Bool)
Union{Bool, Int64}
```